# What Amazon Web Services are most similar to these Azure Web Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure

I'm fairly familiar with a lot of the Amazon Web Services but I'm not trying to get up to speed with a number of Azure Web Services. To help that transition, what AWS services are most similar to these Azure ones:

1. Cosmos Db - I'm guessing AWS Dynamo Db
2. Azure Service Bus - I'm guessing AWS SQS
3. Service fabric
4. Azure Storage (Blob, queues and tables)
5. Azure Functions - I'm guessing this is AWS Lambda
6. App Insights
7. Cloud Services
8. Azure Traffic Manager
9. Azure Load Balancer - I'm guessing AWS Load Balancer
10. Azure Key vault

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, this is a nice list : https://caylent.com/aws-google-azure-cloud-comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has done a nice work of comparing Azure and AWS Services.

You can find this information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/aws-professional/services.